# Wishlist Member redirects some, not all, registrants. Why?

Tags: wordpress

Strange problem with Wishlist Member.

I set up the membership script and sent out a registration URL to 20 or so people who were willing to test-drive the site. However, only a handful of them were able to reach the registration page successfully, whereas the others were redirected to the homepage.

I checked the WLM support where it says this can happen if you enter the destination URL rather than the registration URL, but I definitely didn't do that. I copy and pasted the exact registration URL for that member level.

I've never encountered a problem like this before, where one group of people get one result, but another group get a different result from taking the same action.

I'm in contact with the support guys there, but still looking for a resolution. I upgraded the plugin, made sure everything hit the checklist, and asked those test-drivers to try again. One was able to succeed, the others not.

I was wondering if anyone here had any suggestions? It'd be hugely appreciated.